# How to draw a CGPath with OpenGL?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, core-animation, cgpath

What is the best way of drawing a CGPath with OpenGL?

I'm basically looking for a CAShapeLayer replacement that's drawing with OpenGL.

There's an outline and a fill color, and the most imported thing: Everything is beatifully anti-aliased.

(I know that SpriteKit can do this, but I need the OpenGL drawing code, as I want to batch draw a lot of CGPaths)

Comment: Are you sure that going to OpenGL is the best way forward? It will probably be easier and more maintainable to optimize your Core Animation or Sprite Kit drawing code.

Comment: What makes you think he hasn't exhausted all optimisations available in his existing approach? Surely that's why he's asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a huge task ahead of you then. Time to implement your own version of CGPath in OpenGL.